# BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast - PACKAGE_ADDED in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service, intentfilter

I am getting this exception in my below given code. i don't have any idea what is wrong with this code. Please help me out to get rid of this exception.

```
05-23 23:33:49.853: E/BroadcastReceiver(26895): BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast
05-23 23:33:49.853: E/BroadcastReceiver(26895): java.lang.RuntimeException: BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast
05-23 23:33:49.853: E/BroadcastReceiver(26895):     at android.content.BroadcastReceiver.checkSynchronousHint(BroadcastReceiver.java:783)
05-23 23:33:49.853: E/BroadcastReceiver(26895):     at android.content.BroadcastReceiver.setResultCode(BroadcastReceiver.java:549)
05-23 23:33:49.853: E/BroadcastReceiver(26895):     at com.waypedia.rupesh.abhi.RetentionApplicationAddedBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(RetentionApplicationAddedBroadcastReceiver.java:18)
05-23 23:33:49.853: E/BroadcastReceiver(26895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2446)
05-23 23:33:49.853: E/BroadcastReceiver(26895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:139)
05-23 23:33:49.853: E/BroadcastReceiver(26895):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1286)
05-23 23:33:49.853: E/BroadcastReceiver(26895):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-23 23:33:49.853: E/BroadcastReceiver(26895):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-23 23:33:49.853: E/BroadcastReceiver(26895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
05-23 23:33:49.853: E/BroadcastReceiver(26895):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 23:33:49.853: E/BroadcastReceiver(26895):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-23 23:33:49.853: E/BroadcastReceiver(26895):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
05-23 23:33:49.853: E/BroadcastReceiver(26895):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
05-23 23:33:49.853: E/BroadcastReceiver(26895):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Below is my code:**

```
    public class RetentionApplicationAddedBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            RetentionAddIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK); //**LINE 18**
}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Delete `setResultCode()`. That is only for use with an ordered broadcast, as is described in [the documentation for `setResultCode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#setResultCode%28int%29).

Comment: This may not solve the issue for Android O devices.  I got rid of `setResultCode()` in my class, and still getting this error on Android O from WakefulBroadcastReceiver.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: That doesn't make a lot of sense, as that specific error should only come about by setting a result. You might consider posting a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] (code + stack trace).

Answer (score 4):

The clean way to fix it would be to do as follows:

```
if (isOrderedBroadcast()) {
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

For reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/0J_RBzTQFHs