# BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast Weird Error

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

This error started occurring when the app is launched for the first time even though I am not sending a push notification:

```
 BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast
        java.lang.RuntimeException: BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast
                at android.content.BroadcastReceiver.checkSynchronousHint(BroadcastReceiver.java:799)
                at android.content.BroadcastReceiver.setResultCode(BroadcastReceiver.java:565)
                at com.pushnotification.GcmBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(GcmBroadcastReceiver.java:17)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2712)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

The code for the BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());

        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));

        /* the crash is pointing to this line */
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

The error started showing up after I implemented the following code in an IntentService (also doesn't get called on app launch). But also not every time, I.E. after uninstalling and running the app from Android Studio sometimes the error occurs and sometimes it doesn't.

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver;
public void DownloadListener(final String ZipFile) {
  receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      String action = intent.getAction();

      if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
        long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);

        DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
        query.setFilterById(downloadReference);
        Cursor c = downloadManager.query(query);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
          int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
          if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
            DismissProgressDialog();
            ShowProgress("Almost Done", "Unzipping And Installing Database", pd.STYLE_SPINNER);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  context.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
}
```

In the manifest:

```
<receiver
  android:name="com.pushnotification.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
  android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <category android:name="com.geovision.ffmsnativeprototype" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name=".WebServiceCommunication.SystemDatabaseService" />
```

After commenting out the line `setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);` as recommended by the answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835970/broadcastreceiver-trying-to-return-result-during-a-non-ordered-broadcast-packa) the IntentService for push notification received a notification with this content

```
From-google.com/iid-Title-null-Message-null-ExtraData-null
```

My case is the same as [Weird push message received on app start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479424/weird-push-message-received-on-app-start)

Comment: possible duplicate of [BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast - PACKAGE\_ADDED in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835970/broadcastreceiver-trying-to-return-result-during-a-non-ordered-broadcast-packa)

Comment: i saw the answer and it didnt help

Comment: Did you try deleting setResultCode() ?

Comment: yes i did try. please see my edit

Comment: if you want me to post the OnHandleIntent code for the pushnotification intent service (called from the GcmBroadcastReceiver) i will

Comment: please this is not a duplicate question so remove the above tag that it is a duplicate

Comment: What is the problem your'e facing after removing `setResultCode()`?

Comment: the GcmBroadcastReceiver is being called though i am not sending a notification which is triggering GcmIntentService that is receiving a null message.

Comment: as i said this is a weird error... i am sorry if my explanation is crappy but i really don't know why the  GcmBroadcastReceiver  is being called

Comment: my case is the same as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479424/weird-push-message-received-on-app-start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30508934/1950784

this is a google related feature which is not a big deal and can be filtered programatically.

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)     //RECEIVE THE PUSHNOTIFICATION
    {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
             * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
             * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
             * recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                //   sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                //      sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                //     extras.toString());
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {


                Log.i(TAG, "PUSHNOTIFICATION RECEIVED @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());


                extraData=extras.getString("extraData");
                from=extras.getString("from");
                title=extras.getString("title");
                message=extras.getString("message");

                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString()+" M"+messageType);




 if(title!=null) {
```

> ```
>                     if(from.equals("google.com/iid"))
>                     {
>                         //related to google ... DO NOT PERFORM ANY ACTION
>                     }
>                     else { 
>                       //HANDLE THE RECEIVED NOTIFICATION
>                         }
> ```

Comment: I am too facing this error. Though it seems harmless, can you tell me how to prevent this error popping up?

Comment: is this the proper way to handle this?

Comment: @JithuP.S No, I don't believe that it is the proper way to handle this. Please see my answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31564816/4348328).

Answer (score 3):

The underlying issue here is that the GCM API has changed. As OP indicates, you *can* simply filter this new intent out, but by doing so **you will miss token refresh notifications**.

From the updated GCM [sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm).

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service
    android:name=".MyInstanceIdListenerService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

MyInstanceIdListenerService.java

```
public class MyInstanceIDListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyInstanceIDLS";

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. This call is initiated by the
     * InstanceID provider.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Fetch updated Instance ID token and notify our app's server of any changes (if applicable).
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
}
```

The proper way to fix this issue is to update your implementation for the new API as detailed in the updated [GCM API docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client).

> For existing apps that extend a WakefulBroadcastReceiver, Google
>   recommends migrating to GCMReceiver and GcmListenerService. To
>   migrate:
>
> In the app manifest, replace your GcmBroadcastReceiver with
>   "com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver", and replace the current
>   service declaration that extends IntentService to the new
>   GcmListenerService
>
> Remove the BroadcastReceiver implementation from your client code
>
> Refactor the current IntentService service implementation to use
>   GcmListenerService
>
> For details, see the example manifest and code samples in this page.

I've posted an answer to a related question that pulls out all of the relevant code required to update from the old implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30671071/4348328).